# Determine boundary and whether the set $A = \{(x,y)\in R^2 : x^2 < y <x\}$ is open or closed.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

We have the set $$A = \{(x,y)\in R^2 : x^2 < y <x\}$$

If we notice $\;x^2 < x\;$ if and only if $\;0 \le x <1 $, then the set would be:

$$A = \{(x,y)\in R^2 :  0<y <x<1\}$$

But then I don't know how to continue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No $A=\{(x,y):x^2 < y < x\} \ne \{(x,y):0< y < x< 1\}=B$ because you are ignoring the requirement that $x^2 < y$.  $(\frac 12,\frac 18)\in B$ because $0< \frac 18< \frac 12 < 1$ but $(\frac 12,\frac 18)\not \in A$ because $\frac 18 < (\frac 12)^2 < \frac 12 < 1$.  It'd be more accurate to say $A = \{(x,y)|0 < x^2 < y < x <1\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easiest to construct the set as the intersection of sets that are easier to deal with, like this.
$$\left \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 |y<x \right \}\bigcap \left \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 |x^2<y  \right \}$$

It may be helpful to graph each of these sets. As you've correctly determined, the x coordinates of the set are between 0 and 1, so the boundary must be some subset of $\left \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 |0<x<1\right \}$. Anything in this vertical strip below the curve $y=x^2$ will be out of the set you're interested in, and at each point of this curve, you can find some small $\varepsilon $ (with a specific value depending on the point you pick) such that any point with the same x coordinate where the y coordinate satisfies $x^2<y<x^2+\varepsilon $ is in your set. In other words, every open neighborhood of a point in the strip that lies on the parabola contains points inside your set and points outside your set, so the part of this curve that passes through this strip must form part of the boundary. We can make a similar argument for $y=x$, reversing "above" and "below".

The argument for why the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ is slightly trickier, but if we consider that the lines $y=\frac{x}{2}$ and $y=\frac{3x+1}{2}$ are both continuous and pass through your set as they approach $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ from the left and right, respectively, we can show that any open neighborhood of $(0,0)$ or $(1,1)$ contains points in your set and out of your set, so these points too must be on the boundary.

Now, if $y=x$ ,it is not the case that $y<x$, and if $y=x^2$, it is not the case that $y>x^2$, so this set does not contain its boundary points, making it open in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Answer (score 1):

If $ x\le 0$ then the point $(x,y)$ is not in $ A$ since we must have
$$x>y>x^2\ge 0$$

If $ x\ge 1$ then the point $(x,y)$ is not in $ A$ because $$ x^2 \ge x \ge 1$$

thus
$$A=\{ (x,y)\in (0,1)^2\;\; :y- x^2>0\} \cap \{(x,y)\in(0,1)^2 \;\;  : x-y>0\}$$

The border is the line $y=x$ and a piece of parabola $ y=x^2$.